# Ruby if statements is always else

Tags: ruby, if-statement

```
puts "Commands: /startEngine, /upgrade"
command = gets
if command.include? "/"
    command.slice! "/"
    isStartEngine = command <=> "startEngine"
    if isStartEngine == 0
        puts "Starting engine"
        sleep(1)
        print "3"
        sleep(1)
        print "2"
        sleep(1)
        print "1"
        sleep(1)
        print "GO!"
    else
        puts "Unknown"
    end
end
```

That is my code but it always returns else on if isStartEngine. Using a case doesn't work and I don't know what will and I am new to ruby. Sorry if it is a newbie question. Thank you!

Comment: (1) [`gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) includes the trailing newline so `command` will never be `'startEngine'`, strip off the trailing newline before comparing. (2) The spaceship operator (`<=>`) isn't generally used for equality comparisons, `if command == 'startEngine'` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @muistooshort, "generally" suggests there are exceptions. Care to give one? Would "ever" be better?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Just because I can't think of one doesn't mean there aren't any. My writing background is academic mathematics/sciences so I'm wary of absolutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
command = gets
```

you get back a string with an appended newline character "\n"

If you do

```
command.chomp!
```

that will remove any unwanted whitespace or newline characters.  This should work:

```
puts "Commands: /startEngine, /upgrade"
command = gets
command.chomp!
if command.include? "/"
    command.slice! "/"
    isStartEngine = command <=> "startEngine"
    if isStartEngine == 0
        puts "Starting engine"
        sleep(1)
        print "3"
        sleep(1)
        print "2"
        sleep(1)
        print "1"
        sleep(1)
        print "GO!"
    else
        puts "Unknown"
    end
end
```

Comment: Consider writing simply `if gets.chomp == "/startEngine"; puts "Starting engine"; sleep(1); ...`. You could write `if gets == "/startEngine\n"; ...`, but that causes a problem on Windows machines because `gets` would return `"/startEngine\r\n"`. One would have to write `if gets.match?(/\A\/startEngine\r?\n\z/) ...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Or `case gets.chomp when '/startEngine' ...` since there are already more than one command.